# highcharts tooltip usehtml doesn't work

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

I have used highcharts and used "usehtml=true" in order to display the text in 3 lines and color one of them.

The code for the tooltip is

```
tooltip:
{
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function()
    {
        var color = "";
        if (this.point.config[2]>0) color = "green";
        else if (this.point.config[2]<0) color = "red";
        return '<div style="direction:rtl;"' +
            '<p>שעה:' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) +'</p> <p>indice:'+ this.y + '</p><p> change:</p>' 
            + "<p class='"+color+"'>" + this.point.config[2] + "</p>"+'</div>';
    }
},
```

and you can view in action here
http://s-maof.com/PRO/index3.php?fkapp=2 (mouseover one of the 6 boxs there).

the ironic thing here that it works in IE8(i think 9 too) but not in FF and chrome (funny..)

that's it, any suggestions?

Edited :

I have found that highcharts 2.1.4 doesn't support useHTML property, 
so I upgarded to 2.2.5, 
you can view here
http://s-maof.com/PRO/index4.php?fkapp=2

but now the graphs are not displayed at all, also tried upgrading my jquery version, and nothing.

Comment: Have you tired using <br> tag?

Comment: yes, but the html property is not working in FF not chrome. the tootip tag gets strip out of html

Comment: The <br> tag is working all right with FF in this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-shared/

Comment: Can you provide us with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of what you are working with?

Comment: Also for rtl use: text-align:right

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is incomplete :

```
'<div style="direction:rtl;"' +
```

should be :

```
'<div style="direction:rtl;">' +
```

Answer (score 0):

you must , set direction like this:

```
tooltip: {
 useHTML: true,
 formatter: function() {
 return '<div lang="fa" dir="rtl"> ' +
 this.x + ' : ' + this.y +
 '</div>';
  }
},
```